# why does Jenkins Subversion Tagging Plugin delete old tags

Tags: svn, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that builds the trunk, and uses the plugin "Subversion Tagging" to create a tag after the build is complete.

I'm wondering why it deletes the old tags, and that there's no option to stop this from happening. i.e. one tag is created and the previous one is deleted.

This may be a question regarding svn administration procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: because it was designed that way.

I find that plugin quite restrictive as well, and write my own shell scripts to perform my tagging for me.

Answer (score 0):

Those tags are still in Subversion repository history and you can always look through all of them by running [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) against the `/tags` path or your repository.

Comment: yea i know, but what if they represent say 3 released version that are still being maintained. It doesnt make sense to svn delete them or otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 1.14 and this only deletes the tag which it is about to create, should it exist. So if you include e.g. `${env['BUILD_TAG']}` in your tag, it will look differently on every build and old tags will not get lost that way.